# adding an if else statement to existing PHP script

Tags: php

Hopefully an easy one for you guys. I have an existing loop which I would like to add an else statement to it but when I try, it works but if I do an echo within the else statement i am getting multiple iterations of it so I suspect the else statement is not in the right place or something else needs to happen.

`else { echo "no results found"; }`

Basically I want it to check if this exists:
`array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value']) && in_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'], $oid)`

If not then return the else statement `else { echo "no results found"; }`

```
$count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence']);
$exists = array('utf8String', 'printableString', 'teletexString', 'bmpString', 'universalString');
$oid = array('2.5.4.15', '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3', '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2', 'id-at-streetAddress');
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    foreach($exists as $field) {
        if(
            array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value']) &&
            in_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'], $oid)
        ) {
            $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'][$field];
            $type = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'];
            echo '     ', str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $field), ' : ', str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $type), '   ', $value,"\n";
            break; // stop further looping
        } else { echo "no results found"; }
    }
}
```

Using @GRC's solution the results look like this:

[image]

Comment: why don't you try adding the `break` statement within the else part  as well?

Comment: Do you want to break out of both loops or only out of inner loop?

Comment: Make the `else` and `elseif` and in that check that you are on the last iteration (for both loops), then echo `"no results found"`. This way you are indeed checking through all your items and only outputting when you reached the end. You don't want to add a `break`, because it will not go through the whole loop.

Comment: i added a break; and it helped but still get a few iterations just not as many..

Comment: @GRC, yes i want to break out of both loops if there is no data. If there is data then it should continue through the loop

Comment: @user3436467 you are breaking out of inner loop this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence']);
$exists = array('utf8String', 'printableString', 'teletexString', 'bmpString', 'universalString');
$oid = array('2.5.4.15', '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3', '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2', 'id-at-streetAddress');

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    foreach($exists as $field) {
        if(
            array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value']) &&
            in_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'], $oid)
        ) {
            $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'][$field];
            $type = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'];
            echo '     ', str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $field), ' : ', str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $type), '   ', $value,"\n";
            break; // stop further looping
        } else {
           if($i == 0) {
             echo "No more data";
           }
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: data is returned by surrounded by a many of these errors `Notice:  Use of undefined constant moreData - assumed 'moreData' in C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\certdecode\certdecode.php on line 100`

Comment: can you tell me what is line 100 in your script?

Comment: It was a direct copy/paste `for($i = 0; $i < $count && moreData; $i++) { // << && moreData added`

Comment: sorry I am missing $ in front of moreData :(

Comment: seems like moreData was missing $

Comment: results are still not was is expected.. I am getting one piece of data and then an echo of "no results found".. so again it shouldn't be saying "no results found" if data exists..

Comment: let me know if a screenshot of the output will help?

Comment: I have updated my post with screenshot so you can see the result of your code.. as you can see there is data but your code is only returning one of the data points and then also saying "no results found".

Comment: Thank you for screen shot now I know what do you want, so if there is no data at all you want to show the message if there is a data show the message. I edited my code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `continue 2;` to jump out of the `foreach` and continue with the next `for` iteration if a value *is* found. Then, put your else body  underneath the `foreach`.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    foreach($exists as $field) {
        if(
            array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value']) &&
            in_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'], $oid)
        ) {
            $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'][$field];
            $type = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'];
            echo '     ', str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $field), ' : ', str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $type), '   ', $value,"\n";

            continue 2; // stop looping and continue with for loop
        }
    }
    // nothing found in the whole foreach
    echo "no results found for $i\n";
    break; // jump out
}
```

Comment: While this is correct, I'm thinking the `"No results found"` is for the entire search. So the user would only want to see the message only once.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek True, clarified that part :)

Comment: Hi Jack, i updated my post to show you the results of your code.. seems to be mixing the output with "found data" and the else statement ?

Comment: @user3436467 So what's the expected output supposed to be like?

Comment: I want it so after it checks the loop if it does not find a match `in_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'], $oid)` then go to the else statement to say "no results found"

Comment: `$oid = array('2.5.4.15', '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3', '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2', 'id-at-streetAddress');` if none of the values in the array were found after going through the loop then echo "no results found" -- with your current code its returning both.. makes sense ?

Comment: "no results found" should be be displayed once only

Comment: @user3436467 I've updated my answer to reflect that requirement.

Comment: @Jack, just tried it.. its still returning both data and "no results found"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75673/discussion-between-user3436467-and-jack).

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
     $count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence']);
        $exists = array('utf8String', 'printableString', 'teletexString', 'bmpString', 'universalString');
        $oid = array('2.5.4.15', '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3', '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2', 'id-at-streetAddress');
    $else = false;
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            foreach($exists as $field) {
                if(
                    array_key_exists($field, $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value']) &&
                    in_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'], $oid)
                ) {
                    $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['value'][$field];
                    $type = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][$i][0]['type'];
                    echo '     ', str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $field), ' : ', str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $type), '   ', $value,"\n";
                    break; // stop further looping
                } else { 
                    echo "no results found"; 
                      $else = true;
                        break; 
                    }
            }
          if($else)
              break;
        }
```

Comment: this does not work.. it displays "no results found" when there is data to be returned

Comment: @user3436467 I've mentioned why this will not work in my comment.